# how to make Laser fiche quote page in php (record indert,update, delete and listing)

Tags: php, mysql

I have made one application for laser fiche quote page.

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Make lase fiche  quote page in PHP

create an Order Management System

How can I achieve:

1. create a new data form
2. quote edit data
3. quote delete in listing

**Insert record code :**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function calc(control){ 
        var row = $(control).parent().parent();
        var qty = row.find("input[id^='qty']").val();
        var price = row.find("input[id^='unitprice']").val();
        var laspprice = row.find("input[id^='laspprice']").val();
        row.find("input[id^='subtotal']").val( (qty * price) + (qty *laspprice) );
        var grandTotal = 0;
        $(".subtotal").each(function () {
            var stval = parseFloat($(this).val());
            grandTotal += isNaN(stval) ? 0 : stval;
        });
        $('#grdtot').val(grandTotal.toFixed(2));
    }
</script>
<?php
    $servername = "*****";
    $username = "*****";    
    $password = "*****";
    $dbname = "******";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error){
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $sql = "SELECT id, parrent_id, listitem, unitprice, lsapprice FROM avantlist";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0){
?> 
<div class="lf-quote-page"> 
    <div class="lf-title clearfix">
        <div class="wrap">
            <h1 class="entry-title">Laserfiche Avante Quote</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="lf-content">
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="lf-quote-table">
                <form action="http://10.0.0.16:8080/data2/userdata.php" method="post" id="form">
                    <table id="tblProducts" class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width: 40%;"><b>List Item</b></td>
                                <td><b>Quantity</b></td>
                                <td><b>Unit Price</b></td>
                                <td><b>LSAP Price</b></td>
                                <td><b>Sub-Total</b></td>
                                <td width="150"><b>Select Sub Item</b></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr><td colspan="6"><b>Server</b></td></tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <input type="hidden" class="id" value="<?php $id; ?>" name="id" id="id[]" style="width:300px;"/>
<?php
    $i = 1;
    $j = 1;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $parrent_id = $row['parrent_id'];
        $listitem = $row['listitem'];
        $unitprice = $row['unitprice'];
        $lsapprice = $row['lsapprice'];
        if($parrent_id == 0 || $parrent_id == 2 || $parrent_id == 3) {
            if($row['id']!=='10' && $row['id']!=='14' && $row['id']!=='17' && $row['id']!=='20'){?>
                            <tr data-type="parent<?php echo $i++;?>" id="<?php echo 'row'.$id;?>">
                                <td><input type="text" class="listitem" value="<?php echo $listitem; ?>" name="listitem[]" id="listitem" readonly/></td>
                                <td><input type="text" class="qty" value="0" name="qty[]" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" id="qty" onblur="calc(this)"/></td>            
                                <td><input type="text" class="unitprice" value="<?php echo $unitprice;?>" name="unitprice[]" id="unitprice" readonly/></td>
                                <td><input type="text" class="laspprice" value="<?php echo $lsapprice;?>" name="laspprice[]" id="laspprice" readonly/></td>
                                <td><input type="text" class="subtotal" value="0" name="subtotal[]" id="subtotal" readonly/></td>
                                <td><?php if ($parrent_id == 0) {  ?><input type="checkbox" onchange="showDetails(this)" /></td><?php } ?>
                            </tr>
            <?php } if($row['id']=='10') {?>
                            <tr><td colspan="6"><b><?php echo $listitem;?></b></td></tr>
            <?php } if($row['id']=='14') {?>
                            <tr><td colspan="6"><b><?php echo $listitem;?></b></td></tr>
            <?php } if($row['id']=='17') {?>
                            <tr><td colspan="6"><b><?php echo $listitem;?></b></td></tr>
            <?php } if($row['id']=='20') {?>
                            <tr><td colspan="6"><b><?php //echo $listitem;?></b></td></tr>
            <?php } 
        }elseif($parrent_id == 0 || $parrent_id == 1) {?>
                            <tr data-type="child<?php echo $j++;?>" class="hide">
                                <td><input type="text" class="listname" value="<?php echo $listitem; ?>" name="listname[]" id="listname" readonly/></td>
                                <td><input type="text" class="qty" value="0" name="qty[]" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" id="qty" onblur="calc(this)"/></td>
                                <td><input type="text" class="unitprice" value="<?php echo $unitprice;?>" name="unitprice[]" id="unitprice" readonly/></td>
                                <td><input type="text" class="laspprice" value="<?php echo $lsapprice;?>" name="laspprice[]" id="laspprice" readonly/></td>
                                <td><input type="text" class="subtotal" value="0" name="subtotal[]" id="subtotal" readonly/></td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
    <?php } 
    }?>
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td style="text-align:right;">Total System Price:</td>
                                <td><input type="text" class="grdtot" value="" id="grdtot" name="" readonly/></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
                    <div class="quote-bottom-row clearfix">
                        <div class="quote-lable">
                            <label>Quote name</label> 
                            <input type="text" class="formbox" name="quotename" required><br>
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" class="btn"/>                         
                            <a href="index.php?file=Product_list"><input type="button" value="cancel" name="cancel" class="btn gray-btn"/></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<script type="application/javascript">
    function isNumberKey(evt){
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
            return false;
            return true;
        }
</script>
<script>
    function showDetails(chk) {
        //var animalType = animal.getAttribute("data-type");
        var tr = $(chk).parent().parent();
        var attr = tr.attr("data-type");
        var attr1 = tr.attr("data-type");
        var attr = attr.replace("parent", "child")          
        var t = $("#tblProducts").children('tbody').children('tr').each(function (element) {
            if ($(chk).prop('checked') == true) {
                if ($(this).attr("data-type") == attr) {
                    $(this).addClass("show");
                    $(this).removeClass("hide");
                }
                else {
                    if ($(this).attr("data-type").indexOf("child") != -1) {
                        $(this).addClass("hide");
                        $(this).removeClass("show");
                    }

                    if ($(this).attr("data-type").indexOf("parent") != -1) {

                        if ($(this).attr("data-type") != attr1) {
                            $(this).children().find("input").prop('checked', false);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).children().find("input").prop('checked', false);

                if ($(this).attr("data-type").indexOf("child") != -1) {
                    $(this).addClass("hide");
                }
            }
        });
        //  $(tr).addClass("show");
        //$(tr).removeClass("hide");
    }
</script>
```

**Edit/Delete code : [Edit functionality not working, Delete functionality working]**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calc(control){
        var row = $(control).parent().parent();
        var qty = row.find("input[id^='qty']").val();
        var price = row.find("input[id^='unitprice']").val();
        var laspprice = row.find("input[id^='laspprice']").val();
        row.find("input[id^='subtotal']").val( (qty * price) + (qty *laspprice) );
        var grandTotal = 0;
        $(".subtotal").each(function () {
            var stval = parseFloat($(this).val());
            grandTotal += isNaN(stval) ? 0 : stval;
        });
        $('#grdtot').val(grandTotal.toFixed(2));
    }
</script>
<input type="hidden" name="quoteid" value=<?php echo $_GET['quoteid'];?>>
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['update'])){
        $servername = "****";
        $username = "*****";
        $password = "*****";
        $dbname = "*****";
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error){
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
        $quoteid = $_GET['quoteid'];
        $sql = "DELETE FROM userdata1 WHERE quoteid='$quoteid'";
        echo $sql;
        if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE){
            //echo "Record deleted successfully";
            $servername = "******";
            $username = "******";
            $password = "******";
            $dbname = "*****";
            $conn2 = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
            if($conn->connect_error){
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn2->connect_error);
            }
            $listitem = $_POST['listitem']; 
            $qty = $_POST['qty']; 
            $unitprice = $_POST['unitprice']; 
            $laspprice = $_POST['laspprice']; 
            $subtotal = $_POST['subtotal']; 
            $quotename = $_POST['quotename']; 
            function getGUID(){
                if(function_exists('com_create_guid')){
                    return com_create_guid();
                }
                else{
                    mt_srand((double)microtime()*10000);//optional for php 4.2.0 and up.
                    $charid = strtoupper(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)));
                    $hyphen = chr(45);// "-"
                    $uuid = ""    // "{"
                    .substr($charid, 0, 8).$hyphen
                    .substr($charid, 8, 4).$hyphen
                    .substr($charid,12, 4).$hyphen
                    .substr($charid,16, 4).$hyphen
                    .substr($charid,20,12)
                    ."";  // "}"
                    return $uuid;
                }
            }
            $GUID = getGUID();
            $GUID = str_replace("{","",$GUID );
            $GUID = str_replace("}","",$GUID );
            foreach($_POST['listitem'] as $row=>$Listitem){
                //$username=mysqli_real_escape_string($Listitem);
                //$id=$_POST['id'][$row];
                $listitem=$_POST['listitem'][$row];
                $qty=$_POST['qty'][$row];
                $unitprice=$_POST['unitprice'][$row];
                $laspprice=$_POST['laspprice'][$row]; 
                $subtotal=$_POST['subtotal'][$row];
                $quotename=$_POST['quotename'][$row];
                $sql2 = "INSERT INTO userdata1(listitem, qty, unitprice, laspprice, subtotal, quotename, quoteid)
                    VALUES('$listitem', '$qty', '$unitprice', '$laspprice', '$subtotal', '$quotename','$GUID')"; 
                    //print_r($sql2 .'<br/>');
                $result2 = mysqli_query($sql2)or die(mysqli_error()); 
                //print_r($result2);
            }
            if($result2){ 
                echo "Quote updated successful"; 
                echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"1;URL=http://10.0.0.16:8080/data2/index.php?file=Product_list \">";
            } 
        } 
        else {
            echo "Error deleting record: " . $conn->error;
        }
        $conn->close();
    }

    $servername = "******";
    $username = "*****";    
    $password = "*****";
    $dbname = "****";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error){
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $quoteid = $_GET['quoteid'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM userdata1 WHERE quoteid='$quoteid'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0){
?>
<div class="lf-quote-page"> 
    <div class="lf-title clearfix">
        <div class="wrap">
            <h1 class="entry-title">Laserfiche Avante Quote- Update</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="lf-content">
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="lf-quote-table">
                <form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="post" id="form">
                    <table id="tblProducts" class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width: 40%;"><b>List Item</b></td>
                                <td><b>Quantity</b></td>
                                <td><b>Unit Price</b></td>
                                <td><b>LSAP Price</b></td>
                                <td><b>Sub-Total</b></td>
                                <!--<td width="150"><b>Select Sub Item</b></td>-->
                            </tr>
                            <tr><td colspan="5"><b>Server</b></td></tr>     
                        </thead>
                        <input type="hidden" class="id" value="<?php $id; ?>" name="id" id="id[]" style="width:300px;"/>
                        <tbody>
<?php
    $i = 1;
    $j = 1;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $listitem = $row['listitem'];
        $qty = $row['qty'];
        $unitprice = $row['unitprice']; 
        $laspprice = $row['laspprice'];
        $subtotal = $row['subtotal']; 
        $quotename = $row['quotename'];
        //$quoteid = $row['quoteid'];
    ?>

                            <tr data-type="parent<?php echo $i++;?>" id="<?php echo 'row'.$id;?>">
                                <td><input type="text" class="listitem" value="<?php echo $listitem; ?>" name="listitem[]" id="listitem" readonly/></td>
                                <td><input type="text" class="qty" value="0" name="qty[]" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" id="qty" onblur="calc(this)"/></td>
                                <td><input type="text" class="unitprice" value="<?php echo $unitprice;?>" name="unitprice[]" id="unitprice" readonly/></td>
                                <td><input type="text" class="laspprice" value="<?php echo $laspprice;?>" name="laspprice[]" id="laspprice" readonly/></td>
                                <td><input type="text" class="subtotal" value="0" name="subtotal[]" id="subtotal" readonly/></td>
                            <!--<td><?php //if ($parrent_id == 0) {  ?><input type="checkbox" onchange="showDetails(this)" /></td><?php //} ?>-->
                            </tr>
    <?php } ?>
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td style="text-align:right;">Total System Price:</td>
                                <td><input type="text" class="grdtot" value="" id="grdtot" name="" readonly/></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
                    <div class="quote-bottom-row clearfix">
                        <div class="quote-lable">
                            <label>Quote name</label> 
                            <input type="text" class="formbox" value="<?php echo $quotename; ?>" name="quotename[]" required><br>
                            <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update" class="btn">                      
                            <a href="index.php?file=Product_list"><input type="button" value="cancel" name="cancel" class="btn gray-btn"/></a>
                            <input type="hidden" name="quoteid" value=<?php echo $_GET['quoteid'];?>>                        
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <?php } ?>
<script type="application/javascript">
    function isNumberKey(evt){
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
</script>
<script>
    function showDetails(chk) {
        //var animalType = animal.getAttribute("data-type");
        var tr = $(chk).parent().parent();
        var attr = tr.attr("data-type");
        var attr1 = tr.attr("data-type");
        var attr = attr.replace("parent", "child")

        var t = $("#tblProducts").children('tbody').children('tr').each(function (element) {
            if ($(chk).prop('checked') == true) {
                if ($(this).attr("data-type") == attr) {
                    $(this).addClass("show");
                    $(this).removeClass("hide");
                }
                else {
                    if ($(this).attr("data-type").indexOf("child") != -1) {
                        $(this).addClass("hide");
                        $(this).removeClass("show");
                    }

                    if ($(this).attr("data-type").indexOf("parent") != -1) {

                        if ($(this).attr("data-type") != attr1) {
                            $(this).children().find("input").prop('checked', false);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).children().find("input").prop('checked', false);

                if ($(this).attr("data-type").indexOf("child") != -1) {
                    $(this).addClass("hide");
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "not working", we cannot guess what's not working. Add a description what exactly is not working and what should happen instead. Also, check for error messages and what is the error message you get? Use `var_dump()` to debug the variables you have to check if the content of the variables are the values you are expected. When they are not, tell us what you get and what you want instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load your calc function like this:

```
 window.onload = function() 
    {
    calc();
    };
```

Manage  Radio button Like this:

```
  <?php if($row['id']=='1') {?>
         <input type="radio" name="rad" value="rad1" onchange="showDetails(this);" />       
         <?php } ?>       
         <?php if($row['id']=='2') {?>
         <input type="radio" name="rad" value="rad3" onchange="showDetails(this);" />       
     <?php } ?>

<script>
    if(selValue=='rad1')
                {
                 $(".addqty1").val(1);
                 $("input.addqty1").attr("readOnly", true);
                 $("input.addqty3").attr("disabled", true);
                 $("input.addqty4").attr("disabled", true);
                 $("input.addqty5").attr("disabled", true);
                 $("input.addqty6").attr("disabled", true);          
                 $("input.addqty7").attr("disabled", true);
                 $("input.addqty8").attr("disabled", true);     
                 $("input.addqty9").attr("disabled", true);          
                }       
                else if(selValue=='rad2')
                {
                 $(".addqty2").val(1);
                 $(".subtotal").val('');             
                 $("input.addqty3").attr("readOnly", true);
                  $("input.addqty3").attr("disabled", false);
                 $("input.addqty4").attr("readOnly", true);              
                 $("input.addqty1").attr("disabled", true); 
                 $("input.addqty2").attr("disabled", true);                      
                 $("input.addqty5").attr("disabled", true);
                 $("input.addqty6").attr("disabled", true);          
                 $("input.addqty7").attr("disabled", true);
                 $("input.addqty8").attr("disabled", true);     
                 $("input.addqty9").attr("disabled", true);                          
                }

</script>
```

Not tested, hope this help for you.